# Java PriorityQueue Comparator

Tags: java, hashmap, queue, priority-queue, comparator

Say I've implemented a HashMap in which characters get assigned an ArrayList of values.

I've created a PriorityQueue of those characters in the HashMap, but I'd like to be able to remove the characters according to this priority:

{a, b, c} <- initial queue

{a, b} Remove c since it contains a value in its ArrayList which determines it must be removed first.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Maybe I could just use a normal queue and determine their priority before actually adding them to the queue?

Comment: Never mind, that won't help me.

Comment: What "exactly" is the problem you are facing??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll%28%29

Comment: I don't know how to determine the comparator for this queue.  I'd like be able to remove the c value in my example because it contains a certain a value in it's ArrayList.  However, a PriorityQueue will remove elements according to their natural ordering if a comparator isn't specified.

Comment: Then the comparator should return -1 if the first element has this certain value in its list and the second hasn't, 1 if the second has the element and the first hasn't, and 0 in the other cases (they both have it, or none of them has it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to combine your keys and values into a single object and use a Comparator which acts on these new objects.